# Find a copulas given joint distribution

Tags: self-study, copula

We were given some homework to complete and would like to know how do you calculate the copulas

[image]
I know from the definition that:
  C(X,Y)=FX,Y(Fx^-1, Fy^-1)
and ill have to find the marginals by doing partial derivatives but how do I go further?

Comment: $F_X(x) = F_{X,Y}(x, \infty)$, you don't need the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Gumbel copula is one copula type of Archimedes copula class. To derive it, you need to:

1- know the generation function of this copula.

2- Find the inverse function of the generation function.

3- apply the definition of Archimedean copula.

Following the last 3 steps, you will derive the Gumbel copula.